# Regexp one or more vs n+1 matching

Tags: regex, svg, go, re2

I found a regexp replacement in my go project was incredibly slow, \s+ was being replaced with a single space using regexp.ReplaceAllLiteralString (re2).

It was apparently put there to collapse whitespace in an SVG, regardless of if that's a good idea, when changed to ' {2,}' the operation is 1 tenth the time.

While using \s vs ' ' is a fair difference - but that makes sense, it's 5x the comparisons. But why when using a single space and +, it is 9x slower than with {2,}?

Answer (score 0):

`X+` means "every instance of X that occurs once or more", which means it's equivalent to `{1,}`. You're replacing  (a single blank) as well as       when using `\s+`.

For an SVG document, or any XML document for that matter, using `\s+` is bound to be slow. The following document would require 5 replacements, ignoring newline sequences:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<element attr1="value" attr2="value" attr3="value"/>
```

Now imagine an SVG document that is so much more complex, and it's reasonable that something like `\s{2,}` would be a lot faster than `\s+` (a.k.a. `\s{1,}`)! There'd be 0 replacements in the document above if you used `\s{2,}`!

Comment: Would this mean that replacements are more costly than comparisons? The comparisons for of \s{2,} would seem more costly than \s{1,} - unless they were consuming 2 byte/runes instead of 1 based on the pattern.

Comment: @jpj That depends on the text you're replacing. In the case of XML, `\s{1,}` will almost always find and replace something, potentially resulting in devastating performance. `\s{2,}` may or may not find anything to replace, so it won't be quite so harmful to performance as most of the time comparisons, not replacements, will be the primary factor.